# Validate the dailymotion url using regex method in c#

Tags: c#

how to validate the dailymotion video url using regex c#?.

Comment: Please read [Regex How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), in particular, "Show us what you tried. A link to one of the many online regex testing tools (see link section) with your attempt and some representative data can do wonders. [...] Very general questions tend to receive no answers at all, because the answers would need to be similarly general."

Answer (score 0):

There is a post from author "blatt" on an internet blog about it :
http://cerjam.net/showthread.php?t=14410
 I'm just copying the code below

```
 public enum dailyQuality
    {
        ld, sd, hd, hd720
    }

    public string dailyDownload(string code, dailyQuality quality)
    {
        WebClient aclient = new WebClient();
        string pgdata = aclient.DownloadString("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/" + code);

        string video = null;

        switch (quality)
        {
            case dailyQuality.ld:
                video = Regex.Split(pgdata, "ldURL%22%3A%22")[1];
                break;
            case dailyQuality.sd:
                video = Regex.Split(pgdata, "sdURL%22%3A%22")[1];
                break;
            case dailyQuality.hd:
                video = Regex.Split(pgdata, "hdURL%22%3A%22")[1];
                break;
            case dailyQuality.hd720:
                video = Regex.Split(pgdata, "hd720URL%22%3A%22")[1];
                break;
            default:
                return "...";
        }

        video = Regex.Split(video, "%22%2C%22")[0];

        return makeNormalDaily(video);
    }

    private string makeNormalDaily(string data)
    {
        string astring = data.Replace("%3A", ":");
        astring = astring.Replace("%5C%2F", "/");
        astring = astring.Replace("%3F", "?");
        astring = astring.Replace("%3D", "=");
        return astring;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks xavave!. I need var dailymotionMatch = new Regex(@"/^.+dailymotion.com/(video|hub)/([^_]+)[^#]*(#video=‌​([^_&]+))?/").Match(‌​Url); like this regex format.